# Reactjs-popup library open property is not working

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-popup

<Popup trigger={
<div

```
              onClick={()=>this.setState({isOpen:true})}
            >
              Click
          </div>
      }
            contentStyle={{width:250}}
            position={"bottom left"}
            arrow={false}
            on="click"
            open={this.state.isOpen}
            onClose={()=>this.setState({isOpen:false})}
          >
```

this.setState({isOpen:false)}>open

Is open property working on reactjs-popup library?

Comment: Should be `isOpen` instead of `isOpenCalendar` I guess